# Intune company portal causes USB debugging to automatically switch off

Tags: samsung, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-note, microsoft-intune

I recently installed [Microsoft Intune company portal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.windowsintune.companyportal) on my Samsung Galaxy Note 10+ for work. Unfortunately, doing so resulted in the following change to my USB debugging settings: ["Block - Prevent devices from using the USB debugging feature"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/compliance-policy-create-android-for-work). Once I discovered this, I fully uninstalled and unenrolled from the Intune company portal, however the USB debugging block remains.

I did notice that I can toggle on and use USB debugging for 2-4 minutes after rebooting my phone, but after that, the switch instantly goes back to off when I try to enable it. I've tried resetting my phone settings, re-enabling developer options, and then trying to turn on USB debugging, but the setting still behaves the same. I've also tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496745/usb-debugging-option-on-my-android-keeps-turning-off/54040795#54040795), but the setting remains disabled. Any help undoing what the company portal did to my phone would be massively appreciated.

Note:
I already disabled/uninstalled several apps potentially related to the issue via `adb shell` commands during the first few minutes after rebooting. If I knew which lingering app was responsible for enforcing the USB debugging block, I think uninstalling it would fix the issue. I've disabled several so far with no effect. Hoping to avoid a factory reset.

Phone details/bug screen recording:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uyIRKBnrpW4RH5hmlKJ2mAOMmJXt8j5d?usp=sharing

Comment: Unclear what "resetting my phone settings" means. OP may need to do a full factory reset, but should backup/save all data as the phone will be wiped. Hopefully that will restore developer controls.

Comment: sorry, reset as in:
Samsung settings app > general management > reset > reset all settings
"this will reset all of the settings on your phone"

Comment: clearUserRestriction DISALLOW_DEBUGGING_FEATURES
Apparently, the block may be enforced via devicepolicymanager after each restart: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager#DISALLOW_DEBUGGING_FEATURES

Comment: maybe something like:
adb shell pm set-user-restriction --user 0 no_debugging_features 0